# Axis/label under pie chart - echarts

Tags: laravel, echarts

I am using echarts library through the Chartisan package on Laravel, but when I render pie charts there is a line that is rendered under the piechart. How can I get rid of the line below the pie chart?
[eCharts Pie Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBV29.png)

```
const goods_chart = new Chartisan({
            renderer: 'svg',
            el: '#goods_category_chart',
            url: "@chart('goods_category_chart')",
            hooks: new ChartisanHooks()
                //.colors(['#4299E1','#62051f','#C07EF1','#67C560','#ECC94B'])
                .title({
                          text:'Goods by Category (YTD)',
                          subtext:'Tonnes',
                          left:'center'
                })
                .legend({
                    orient: 'vertical',
                    left: 10,
                },)
                .datasets([{
                    type:'pie',
                    animationEasing: 'cubicInOut',
                    radius: ['45%', '70%'],
                    labelLine: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    emphasis: {
                        label: {
                            show: true,
                            fontSize: '15',
                            fontWeight: 'bold'
                        },
                        itemStyle:{
                            shadowBlur:10,
                            shadowOffsetX:0,
                            shadowColor:'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)'
                        }
                    },

                }])
                .tooltip({trigger: 'item',formatter: "{a} <br/>{b} : {c} ({d}%)"}),
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try adding .axis(false) This should work.

Comment: someone says how to define a step size of y axes?